# Send email in workflow list showing error SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

[image: I select "To address" from current field]

I have facing the below error :

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to
>   http://mysiteDemo/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44475/discussion-on-question-by-admin-send-email-in-workflow-list-showing-error-sharep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to set a variable to get information from "Person & Group" Column and then you used in "Assign a Task" action

1- The Veriable must be a Type of Integer

2- as well as Current item

[image]
[image]

if you use "Send an Email" action then u need to do it on this way

[image]

Comment: Hey i am not able to set variable. when i select current item . my distribution filed ok button is disable. I thing type issue. it must to integer type variable ?

Comment: hmm...!! yeeeh the local variable must be Int

Comment: I am not able to set value to my variable, b'ce distribution filed type is person or Group.

Comment: I update my Answar

Comment: yeeeh :) :) please mark my answar as useful

Comment: I have one query my old workflow is not started when i click on start workflow it show only alert "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" but when i create new its work.